# Do StreamPlot and VectorPlot work with Piecewise?

Tags: plotting

Executing

```
StreamPlot[{Piecewise[{{-1, z < -1}, {z, 1 >= z && z >= -1}, 
{1, z > 1}}] , -x}, {z, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}]
```

, I see an error message "Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist." which I don't understand
and a square in rose. I don't find such type examples in the documentation.
The same issue with `VectorPlot`. The commands, where the field under consideration is rewritten
in other formulas,

```
StreamPlot[{Max[Min[z, 1], -1], -x}, {x, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

and

```
StreamPlot[{If[z < -1, -1, If[z > 1, 1, z]], -x}, {x, -5, 5}, {z, -5,  5}]
```

work well, resulting in

[image]

ODE systems with piecewise functions are common in control theory.
The question arises: does `StreamPlot/VectorPlot` handle  `Piecewise`?

Comment: you can do `StreamPlot[
 Piecewise[{{{-1, -x}, z < -1}, {{z, -x},  1 >= z && z >= -1}, {{1, -x}, z > 1}}], {z, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}]` or ``StreamPlot[{Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
   Piecewise[{{-1, z < -1}, {z, 1 >= z && z >= -1}, {1,   z > 1}}], -x}, {z, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}]``

Comment: @kglr: Thank you. Unfortunately, the result of `StreamPlot[
 Piecewise[{{{-1, -x}, z < -1}, {{z, -x}, 
    1 >= z && z >= -1}, {{1, -x}, z > 1}}], {z, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}]` differs from the correct result. Did you execute your codes before having posted those?

Comment: yes;  puzzling indeed.

Comment: @user64494 The first line in your question has a reversed order of `x` and `z` compared to the lines below.

Comment: Adding a ?NumericQ pattern test should eliminate the message, too.

Comment: @rnotlnglgq; You wrote " The first line in your question has a reversed order of x and z compared to the lines below", This does not matter: execute `StreamPlot[{Piecewise[{{-1, z < -1}, {z, 1 >= z && z >= -1}, {1, 
     z > 1}}], -x}, {x, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]` with the same result.

Comment: I'm not trying to answer the question, but explaining why the code from @kglr is different from "the correct result".

Comment: @rnotlnglgq; The correctness is confirmed by `sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
     Piecewise[{{-1, z[t] < -1}, {z[t], z[t] >= -1 && z[t] <= 1}, {1, 
        z[t] > 1}}], z'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 0, z[0] == 2}, {x[t], 
    z[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];ParametricPlot[{x[t], z[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]`.